# Returning all validation errors at once using embedded documents in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose

I am building a REST API that enables users to POST a document that can contain several embedded documents. I have set up some validation rules both for the main document and the embedded documents.

When I make a request that has invalid data, then Mongoose first check the embedded documents for validation errors and whenever one of them fails, it will return the error, and ignore the rest of the document.

From a API consumer perspective, I think I'd like to get all the errors at once - both for all the embedded documents as well as the main document.

So my 2 questions are:

1. What is the reasoning behind this design in Mongoose?
2. Is there ar way to validate all documents and then return the errors at once?

Comment: I'm not the architect, but I would think it comes down to resources. Because of the async nature... its less costly to stop at the first sign of trouble then to walk the tree.

Comment: I agree that it's cheaper thsi way but... it is utlimately bad behaviour - a user should be able to correct any validation errors all at once, not submit, get an error, correct, re-submit, get next error, correct it, re-submit, etc..